# Probability Law vs Probability Mass Function

Tags: probability-theory

For a given probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ on which we have defined a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, we define the Probability Law of $X$ as $$P_X(B) = P(X^{-1}(B)) = P\{\omega \in \Omega|X(\omega) \in B\}, \forall B \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}),$$
where $\mathfrak{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra.

We define the pmf of the random variable $X$ as $p_X(x) = P(X=x)$. However, $P$ is a measure on $\mathcal{A}$, not on the images of the subsets of $\mathcal{A}$ under $X$. It seems to me, then, that this statement can only make sense if we read it as: $$p_X(x) = P(X^{-1}(x)) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega| X(\omega)= x\}).$$ But this is just a restatement of the Probability Law.

If my understanding is correct and the pmf is just the Probability Law, why the new name pmf and the new symbol $p_X$? If my understanding is NOT correct then I am in big trouble and need help.

Comment: The law is a measure. The probability mass function is just a function.

Comment: Too close to see the wood for the trees. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law $\mu_X$ of a scalar random variable $X$ is an object that takes a (Borel) subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and returns a number. It makes sense to talk about the law of a variable of any type (discrete, continuous, or any other kind).

The probability mass function $p_X$ of a scalar discrete random variable $X$ is an object that takes an element of $\mathbb{R}$ and returns a number. It does not make sense to talk about probability mass function if the variable is not discrete.

In case of discrete variables, the law and probability mass function pretty much contain the same information.
To get the pmf out of law write:
$$
p_X(x) = \mu_X(\{ x \}).
$$
To get the law out of pmf write
$$
\mu_X(A) = \sum_{a \in A} p_X(a).
$$

A comment regarding the notation: you are right that things like $P(X=x)$ and $P(X \in A)$ are just shortened versions of $P(\{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega)=x \})$, and $P(\{\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \in A \})$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you. This is very clear. I think my head is on straight again, for now.

Comment: Thank you. This is very clear. I think my head is on straight again, for now.